# Updating dynamic HTML table using PHP and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic-tables

I am pretty new to PHP so i am experimenting at home a bit. I have setup a local server. Been trying for some while now but i am having issues solving this last part. I am not sure how to connect the last pieces.

This is my **Index.php**:

```
<?php
    //readfile("show.html");
    $jobs;
    $rssFeed = kungsorJobsFetcher();
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
    echo rss_kungsor_items_beautify1(getItems(), $page, 1000000);

    function kungsorJobsFetcher(){


        $feed = implode(file('https://recruit.visma.com/External/Feeds/AssignmentList.ashx?guidGroup=221caebb-3836-4036-8c83-edd6e630ec79'));
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
        $res = array();
        foreach($xml->Assignments->Assignment as $job){
            list($date, $trash) = explode( 'T', $job->ApplicationEndDate );
            $item["date"] = $date;
            $item["link"] = $job->ReadMoreUrl;
            $item["city"] = $job->AccountName;
            foreach($job->Localization->AssignmentLoc->AssignmentTitle as $jobTitle){
                $item["title"] = $jobTitle;
            }
            array_push($res, $item);
        }

        $GLOBALS['jobs'] = $res;
    }

    function getItems() {
      //  print_r($GLOBALS['jobs']);
        return $jobs;
    }
    function rss_kungsor_items_beautify1($items, $page = 0, $length = 5, $link = ""){
        //$full_items = $items;;
        $items = $GLOBALS['jobs'];
        //$items = array_slice($items, $page*$length, $length);
        $markup = '';
        $markup = file_get_contents('table_header_kungsor.tpl.php', true);

        $rows = '';

        if(count($items) > 0) {
            foreach($items AS $item) {
                $link_item = $item['link'];
                if ($link != "") {
                    $link_item = $link;
                }

                $date = date_format(date_create($item['date']), 'Y-m-d');

                if (strpos($item["date"], '/') !== false){
                    $date = date_format(strtotime($item['date']), 'Y-m-d');
                }


                $rows .= "<tr><div class='annons-item kungsor-item'>" .
                "<div class='left'>";

                $rows .= "<div class='content'>" .
                        "<h4><a class='kungsor-link' target='_blank' href='$link_item'>" . $item['title'] . "</a></h4>" .
                        "<div class='subcontent'>" .
                        "<div class='item'><p>" . $item['city'] . "</p></div>" .
                            "<div class='item'><p>Sista ansökningsdag: $date</p></div>" .
                        "</div>" .
                    "</div>" .
                "</div>" .
                "<a target='_blank' href='$link_item' class='apply-btn hiddenSM'>Ansök här</a>" .
                "</div></tr>";
            }
    }
    $markup = preg_replace('/\{rows\}/', $rows, $markup);
    return $markup;
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var simple = '<?php echo $GLOBALS['jobs']; ?>';
    jQuery('body').on('keyup','input.test',function(){
        console.log(simple);
    });
</script>
```

And this is my **table.header.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Enter your name: <input class="test" type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">

  <table>
    <tr>
      {rows}
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

What i am looking for:

As you can see the table are populated with the variable `rows`. Whenever a user types in the input field i want it too look through all the titles and show only the relevant ones
I was thinking making a foreach loop to go through all the items(rows), split the title string and search for matching words. If it matches then we will add it to a temporary array. When all is done update rows with the results(is this a good solution or is there a better efficient one?)
I know what i want to do but i dont know how to do it. A simple example or some explanation or even better some example codes would be awesome! Thanks!

You can copy and paste the code and you should see some rows that are fetching data from the xml provided for easier testing.

I have setup a similar structure from what it looks in my webserver with all the minimal requirements to show what is relevant. Using this method where you echo out a php variable that contains all the html markup etc..

So to summarize. With each keyup on my input field. My keyup function will fire. Using the information from that field to search for the titles containing in the $jobs variable. How do i make the html re render the table automatically?

Comment: You should obfuscate your endpoint.

Comment: its a public endpoint @DeepakSingh